# How to update the WooCommerce cart Icon to show new products added with JavaScript

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, jquery

I created some custom links to add new products to the cart using the "href" attribute, my code looks like this.

```
<a class="line1" id="btn2" href="?add-to-cart=5207">Example</a>
```

But I didn't like the fact that every time I added a product it refreshed the whole page so I started looking for a different approach, and I found a way to do it with some jQuery code, It's adding the product but as the page is not reloading the cart icon doesn't update until I reload the page manually. The code looks like this.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ){   
    $('#buy').click(function(e) {
       console.log('Working!!')
       e.preventDefault();
       prodId = $(this).attr("data-prod-id");
       addToCart(prodId);
       return false;
    });    

    function addToCart(p_id) {
       $.get('?add-to-cart=' + p_id, function() {
           // call back
       });
     }
});
```

Is there a way to add some code to my jQuery function in order to update only the cart icon so that it shows the new products added?

Answer (score 1):

Heres a nice article describing how to do this, but a very different approach to yours  :
https://aceplugins.com/ajax-add-to-cart-button-on-the-product-page-woocommerce/

Since you know how many items are being added to the cart (1 based on your link) you could just fake some addition and upate the cart icon value

Assuming the cart icon number has an id 'cart-icon' Eg :

```
 function addToCart(p_id) {
   $.get('?add-to-cart=' + p_id, function() {
      // SO IF YOU ALREADY HAD 3 IN CART IT WILL NOW BE 4
       $('#cart-icon').text( $('#cart-icon').text() + 1);

   });
 }
```